# How to change timezone format for user/site settings?

Tags: 7, forms, datetime

I want to change the user configurable timezone format on the regional settings and user settings form.

For example, it displays as `Asia/Kolkata: Friday, October 9, 2015 - 17:24 +0530` I want to display it as `Asia/Kolkata`. I have used following code but not working.

```
function my_modue_form_system_regional_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
dpm(timezone_identifiers_list());
dpm($form);
$form['timezone']['date_default_timezone']['#options'] = timezone_identifiers_list();
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're close. The problem with the above code is that it doesn't set the correct key values in `#options`; thus upon saving, the `date_default_timezone` variable will be set to some numeric key instead of an accepted [PHP timezone string](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) that is expected for the variable.

Do something like this to set the correct key:

```
function token_form_system_regional_settings_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $options = array();
  foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $timezone) {
    //$options[$timezone] sets the value for date_default_timezone select
    //$timezone set the display for select
    $options[$timezone] = $timezone;
  }
  $form['timezone']['date_default_timezone']['#options'] = $options;
}
```

Comment: It is shows only in regional settings form not in user profile form. I have tried same code but not working

Comment: The same code won't work; you'll need to alter `$form['timezone']['timezone']['#options'] = $options;` if you're talking about the `user_profile_form` form.

Comment: It works now @Shawn Conn