# Change timezone display format in user edit page

Tags: 7, forms, datetime

In drupal 7 timezone field in user edit will be like `Asia/Kolkata: Friday, October 9, 2015 - 17:24 +0530`. I want to display it like `Asia/Kolkata`. I have tried the method specifed in https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/177073/50991 but not working. How to change the display format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `$form['#after_build']` should work for you

```
function module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id ==  'user_profile_form') {
    $form['#after_build'][] = 'module_user_profile_form_after_build';
  }
}

function module_user_profile_form_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  $options = array();
  foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $timezone => $value) {
    //$options[$timezone] sets the value for date_default_timezone select
    //$timezone set the display for select
    $options[$timezone] = $value;
   }
   $element['account']['timezone']['timezone']['#options'] = $options;
   return $element;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with below code

```
    function yourcustomodulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id=='user_profile_form'){
 $form['#after_build'][] = 'yourmodulename_after_build'; 

    }
    }
function yourmodulename_after_build($form, &$form_state) { 
      $options = array();
      foreach(timezone_identifiers_list() as $timezone) {
        //$options[$timezone] sets the value for date_default_timezone select
        //$timezone set the display for select
        $options[$timezone] = $timezone;
      }
      $form['account']['timezone']['timezone']['#options'] = $options;
return $form;
}
```

Comment: Not working. I am not seeing any ['account']['timezone'] when dpm() is used @zhilevan

Comment: @Harsha dpm $form, and see where is it,

Comment: No it is not showing timezone field, when I user $form['after build'] it is visible but working.

Comment: @Harsha I update my answer